# Variable in for loop undefined outside

Tags: go, scope

I am wondering why the following piece of code is not working:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        var randomString = fmt.Sprintf("a%sa\n", "test")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Made 10000 random strings like", randomString);
}
```

I've stripped some unrelevant code (as this is obviously not really random).

The issue i'm having is that just under the for-loop, "randomString" is undefined.

I've tried setting it using `randomString := fmt.Sprintf()` and with the var you've seen above.

I'm quite sure this is a scoping issue (the randomString variable is not in the scope outside of the for-loop), but as a PHP / JS developer, i'm not used to this and would say that variable is also available after the for loop.

How can I access that variable from that point? Basically just displaying the last generated string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the relevant section from the spec: [Declarations and scope](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope):

> The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable declarations) and **ends at the end of the innermost containing block**.

Define it in the scope in which you want to access it: before the `for` (in the scope of the `main()` function).

Also note that [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) requires an additional parameter besides the ones to be printed: a format string. Either provide a format string (e.g. include a `%s` verb for the `randomString` parameter) or alternatively you may use [`fmt.Sprintln()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintln).

```
func main() {
    var randomString string
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        randomString = fmt.Sprintf("a%sa\n", "test")
    }
    fmt.Println("Made 10000 random strings like", randomString)
}
```

Output:

```
Made 10000 random strings like atesta
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/IKHK3Z_Uec).

Comment: Ah! That was so obvious I didn't see it. Great, thank you :)

Comment: And indeed, i forgot the %s in the formatted string. But Println works well for this too.

Answer (score 2):

This is scoping issue, in Go the scope of `randomString` is the loop body, in JS it would be the whole function. Scoping rules differ in the different languages.

Check the Go spec:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

Comment: Thanks, but I've checked that page before asking the question - it didn't clear things out for me. I knew I had scoping issues so thats why I asked.

Comment: @RobQuist The relevant part for this case would be "The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the innermost containing block."

Comment: Exactly :) Thanks for the effort though!